# Salesforce Analytics (SAQL)

Tags: einstein-analytics, saql

I would like to pass current year( ["current Year"])  and current month ( ["current month"])   as the dynamic value for month and year  instead of the hard coded value . Please let me know how I will able to pass the string year and month to the  filter.

```
q= load "plan";
q=filter q by 'Type__c'  =="Renewal";
q= filter q by 'Plan.Name' == "2018";
q= filter q by 'inMonth' == "12";
```

Comment: when I tried to convert the numeric to string using the function number_to_string('month_in_number',"##")=date_to_string(now(), "MM"); ,  it is giving me   FUNC instead of IDTOKEN Error . Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `date_to_string` to get a specific part of a date. If you use `now()` it will give you the requested part of the current date. For example:

```
q= load "plan";
q=filter q by 'Type__c'  =="Renewal";
q= filter q by 'Plan.Name' == date_to_string(now(), "yyyy");
q= filter q by 'inMonth' == date_to_string(now(), "MM");
```